# What data type does VBA timer use

Tags: vba

Would like to insert the result of a Visual Basic timer into a database table however I am not sure of what data type the Visual Basic timer function uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a `single`, you can determine this yourself:

```
?typename(timer)
Single
```

Comment: Or by reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264416(v=office.15).aspx) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can find details about most objects and their members in the Object Browser.

For example, you'll find that `Timer` isn't actually a function at all, but is actually a read-only property.

Just press F2 in the VBE, then search or browse for the identifier that you're interested in.

[image]

If you're looking for higher resolution timers, you should search for Win32 functions like `GetTickCount` and `QueryPerformanceCounter`.